# is it possible to open a file stored in memory and not in disk?

Tags: file, c#-4.0, filestream

I have a C# application that open a file with the default application, that's works fine, but I would like to know if there are a better solution, because my case is the following:

- I get the binary from the database. At this moment I have the file in memory, in an objetct.
- I save the binary in a file on the disk, in a temporal folder.
- I open the file with the default application.

I would like to know if it is possible to open the file from the binary data in the object that I have in the first step, when I get the binary information from the database.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Perhaps using a `MemoryStream`, what kind of application opens the _file_? `var stream = new MemoryStream(yourBytes);`

Comment: and, for example, if the file is a pdf, how can I open the file with acrobat reader?

Comment: If you have to use `Process.Start` you should use a temp file. Apart from that, i'm not familiar with Adobe PDF Library SDK. There might be a direct way.

Comment: well, I said adobe for example, but any other default application such as sumatrPDF, FoxIt... etc. But it seems that I need a temporal file in this case.